# PHP routing not redirecting

Tags: php, rest, http, routes

I am trying to create simple Router in PHP and I can't figure out why its no redirecting corectly.

So the way my setup works is I have 3 routes

- the home route "/"
- the user route "/user"
- the user with id route "/user?id={[0-9]}"

When I redirect to "/" route this is what gets printed.

```
/ Path / traversed
```

However I want this to be printed

```
/ Succesfuly navigated to / Path / traversed
```

However none of this works for any of the other paths.
This is what I get when I redirect to "/user"

```
/user Not Found
```

And this is what I want to be rendered.

```
/user Succesfuly navigated to /user Path /user traversed
```

So this is my script for Router.php

```
<?php 

    class Router{

        public function get($route, $callback){

            $path = $this->getPath(); //GET PATH for ex. /users/user
            $query = $this->getQuery(); //GET QUERY for ex. ?id=15

            print($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            echo " ";

            //IF USER IS NAVIGATING TO ROUTE THAT DOESN'T EXIST PRINT "NOT FOUND"
            if($path != $route){
                $this->notFound(); 
            }

            if($path == $route){

                //IF CALLBACK IS A STRING DO SOMETHING WITH IT
                if(is_string($callback)){
                    echo "Succesfuly navigated to {$route}";
                    exit();
                }
                
                //EXECUTE CALLBACK FUNCTION
                echo call_user_func($callback);
                exit();
            }
          
        }

        //GET PATH FROM URI
        private function getPath(){
            $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?? '/';
            $paramPosition = strpos($path, "?");

            if($paramPosition === false){
                return $path;
            }

            $path = substr($path, 0, $paramPosition);
            return $path;
        }

        //GET QUERY STRING ?id=15
        private function getQuery(){

            $path = $_GET;
            if(count($path) == 1){
                return $path;
            }
 
            return $path;
        }


        //404 TEXT
        private function notFound(){
            http_response_code(404);
            echo "Not Found";
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

any this is my index.php

```
<?php

    include_once './core/Router.php';

    $router = new Router();

    $router->get("/", function() {
        echo "Path / traversed";
    });

    $router->get("/user", function() {
        echo "Path /user traversed";
    });

    $router->get("/user?id={[0-9]}", function(){
        echo "Path /user?id={[0-9]} traversed";
    });


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems I can see with this code:

**1. "Not found" messages for routes other than `/`**

The reason this is happening is because you are `exit()`ing in the `notFound` method. You check the / route first, it doesn't match, it outputs "Not Found", then exits.

What you can do instead is remove the `exit()` and return from `get` when not found:

```
//IF USER IS NAVIGATING TO ROUTE THAT DOESN'T EXIST PRINT "NOT FOUND"
if($path != $route){
    $this->notFound();
    return;
}
```

**2. "Successfully navigated to" not appearing**

This happening because you are checking for `is_string`, however your callbacks are functions so this condition will never be true. You can change the condition to `is_callable`:

```
//IF CALLBACK IS A STRING DO SOMETHING WITH IT
if(is_callable($callback)){
    echo "Succesfuly navigated to {$route}";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Well it kinda fixed my problem, but it still doesn't work properly, the Path <path here> traversed get printed succesfully but now the Not Found gets still printed.

For example the path "/user" still prints "< Not Found > Path /user traversed ====" and 
If I add new path "/user/admin" this gets printed "< Not Found > < Not Found > Path /user/admin traversed ==== "

Comment: Ah yep of course, because each call you make to `get` that isn't the matched route prints that it is not found. What you need to do is register the valid routes first (so you have a list to compare against), then a method that dispatches the request.